# regex replace multiple string in the same time

Tags: angular

i want to replace 2 string by 2 values in some time.
when i do this.

```
date1="Date (1995,12,17)"
this.formControlValue=this.formControlValue.replace(/\$RepStartDate/i,date1)
```

it work perfectly.
but when i do this:

```
this.formControlValue=this.formControlValue.replace(/\$RepStartDate/i,date1)
this.formControlValue=this.formControlValue.replace(/\$RepEndDate/i,date2)
```

just the first string is replaced,the other string is not converted.
how can i replace 2 string in some time?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

easily:

```
this.formControlValue=this.formControlValue.replace(/\$RepStartDate/i,date1)
.replace(/\$RepEndDate/i,date2)
```

replace() return string you can replace it again.